# cannot log into Messages and FaceTime in MacOS Big Sur beta 8

Tags: macos, messages

a day ago I updated to macOS Big Sur beta 8. all of the messages I sent said not delivered when I  had internet. I tried logging out and logging back in, but it won't log in. It works for a few seconds and then shows the login screen again. facetime also won't log in.

Comment: Report this using the feedback tool, it is likely a bug in the OS.

Comment: I did. but I think it's not a problem with the OS. some people do not have this problem, and other people had this problem in an earlier beta

Comment: Ever get this resolved?

Comment: @Joseph I did fix it, but I think the only way is to call apple support, and keep insisting that it's not your computer's fault, because they will recommend to downgrade or something first, but that it's a problem with the Apple ID. and after they transfer you to like 25 different people  someone would just fix it

Comment: @TonyZhang wow, sounds super easy, hardly an inconvenience :) but seriously though, thank you for following up with me. I guess I'll bite the bullet and give them a call. Thank you!